# Installed sbt 0.13.9 but mac terminal keeps running 0.12.4

Tags: sbt

I have installed sbt 0.13.9 through brew but somehow after I change directory, it keeps trying to download sbt 0.12.4.

Am I supposed to bring the 0.13.9 .jar file to every directory that I work in?

```
Last login: Tue Sep  1 07:21:38 on ttys001
vtmbpr:~ VT$ sbt sbtVersion
[info] Set current project to vt (in build file:/Users/VT/)
[info] 0.13.9
vtmbpr:~ VT$ cd assignment/example
vtmbpr:example VT$ sbt
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.12.4 ...
```

Thanks to the first answer I changed the code in build properties. However, while sbt seems to be running fine at the beginning of load but failed eventually. What does that unresolved dependency mean?

I am pasting the whole session of code but really the error seems to show only at the very end.

```
Last login: Wed Sep  2 07:29:49 on ttys000
vtmbpr:~ VT$ cd assignment/example
vtmbpr:example VT$ sbt
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/VT/assignment/example/project/project
[info] Updating {file:/Users/VT/assignment/example/project/project/}example-build-build...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-sbt-c5d1b95fdcc1e1007740ffbecf4eb07[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/VT/assignment/example/project
[info] Updating {file:/Users/VT/assignment/example/project/}example-build...
[info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.1.4 ..[info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcomponents-co[info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcomponents-co[info] Resolving net.databinder#dispatch-futures_2.10;0.8.8 [info] Resolving net.databinder#dispatch-futures_2.10;0.8.8 [info] Resolving cc.spray#spray-json_2.10;1.1.1 ...
[warn]  module not found: cc.spray#spray-json_2.10;1.1.1
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/cc.spray/spray-json_2.10/1.1.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/cc.spray/spray-json_2.10/1.1.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/VT/.ivy2/local/cc.spray/spray-json_2.10/1.1.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== jcenter: tried
[warn]   https://jcenter.bintray.com/cc/spray/spray-json_2.10/1.1.1/spray-json_2.10-1.1.1.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/cc/spray/spray-json_2.10/1.1.1/spray-json_2.10-1.1.1.pom
[warn] ==== Spray Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.spray.io/cc/spray/spray-json_2.10/1.1.1/spray-json_2.10-1.1.1.pom
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;2[info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;2.1.0 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;2.1.0
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbteclipse/sbteclipse-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.1.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbteclipse/sbteclipse-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.1.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/VT/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.sbteclipse/sbteclipse-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.1.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== jcenter: tried
[warn]   https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/typesafe/sbteclipse/sbteclipse-plugin_2.10_0.13/2.1.0/sbteclipse-plugin-2.1.0.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/sbteclipse/sbteclipse-plugin_2.10_0.13/2.1.0/sbteclipse-plugin-2.1.0.pom
[warn] ==== Spray Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.spray.io/com/typesafe/sbteclipse/sbteclipse-plugin_2.10_0.13/2.1.0/sbteclipse-plugin-2.1.0.pom
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#launcher-interface;1.0.0-M1 .[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#compiler-integration;0.13.9 .[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#incremental-compiler;0.13.9 .[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbinary#sbinary_2.10;0.4.2 [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#compiler-ivy-integration;0.13[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-sbt-c5d1b95fdcc[info] Resolving org.scala-lang.modules#scala-pickling_2.10;[info] Resolving com.thoughtworks.paranamer#paranamer;2.6 ..[info] Resolving org.spire-math#json4s-support_2.10;0.6.0 ..[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/databinder/dispatch-http_2.10/0.8.8/dispatch-http_2.10-0.8.8.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] net.databinder#dispatch-http_2.10;0.8.8!dispatch-http_2.10.jar (1258ms)
[info] downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/scalastyle/scalastyle_2.10/0.3.2/scalastyle_2.10-0.3.2.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scalastyle#scalastyle_2.10;0.3.2!scalastyle_2.10.jar (3836ms)
[info] downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/scalatest/scalatest_2.10/1.9.1/scalatest_2.10-1.9.1.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scalatest#scalatest_2.10;1.9.1!scalatest_2.10.jar (5899ms)
[info] downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.1/commons-lang3-3.1.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.apache.commons#commons-lang3;3.1!commons-lang3.jar (2695ms)
[info] downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/databinder/dispatch-core_2.10/0.8.8/dispatch-core_2.10-0.8.8.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] net.databinder#dispatch-core_2.10;0.8.8!dispatch-core_2.10.jar (1700ms)
[info] downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/databinder/dispatch-futures_2.10/0.8.8/dispatch-futures_2.10-0.8.8.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] net.databinder#dispatch-futures_2.10;0.8.8!dispatch-futures_2.10.jar (986ms)
[info] downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.1.3/httpclient-4.1.3.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.1.3!httpclient.jar (2746ms)
[info] downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.1.4/httpcore-4.1.4.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.1.4!httpcore.jar (2003ms)
[info] downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1!commons-logging.jar (1019ms)
[info] downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.4/commons-codec-1.4.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] commons-codec#commons-codec;1.4!commons-codec.jar (1016ms)
[info] downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/scalariform/scalariform_2.10/0.1.4/scalariform_2.10-0.1.4.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scalariform#scalariform_2.10;0.1.4!scalariform_2.10.jar (6313ms)
[info] downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/scopt/scopt_2.10/2.1.0/scopt_2.10-2.1.0.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.github.scopt#scopt_2.10;2.1.0!scopt_2.10.jar (1910ms)
[info] downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/scala-lang/scala-actors/2.10.0/scala-actors-2.10.0.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-actors;2.10.0!scala-actors.jar (3120ms)
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: cc.spray#spray-json_2.10;1.1.1: not found
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;2.1.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.typesafe.sbteclipse:sbteclipse-plugin:2.1.0 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      cc.spray:spray-json_2.10:1.1.1 (/Users/VT/assignment/example/project/buildSettings.sbt#L7-8)
[warn]        +- default:example-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
[warn]      com.typesafe.sbteclipse:sbteclipse-plugin:2.1.0 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13) (/Users/VT/assignment/example/project/buildSettings.sbt#L22-23)
[warn]        +- default:example-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: cc.spray#spray-json_2.10;1.1.1: not found
unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;2.1.0: not found
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:294)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:191)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:168)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:155)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:155)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:132)
    at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:57)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$4.call(Ivy.scala:65)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:65)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:127)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:124)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:155)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:168)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1392)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1388)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$90.apply(Defaults.scala:1422)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$90.apply(Defaults.scala:1420)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:37)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1425)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1419)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:60)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1442)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1371)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1325)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: cc.spray#spray-json_2.10;1.1.1: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;2.1.0: not found
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your `project/bulld.properties` file.

If it doesn't exist, create it with something like

```
sbt.version=0.13.9
```